# How can I force docker pull from custom images for Google AI Platform Notebooks?

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I'm creating custom docker images for Google AI Platform Notebooks as documented in https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/custom-container

But I can't find out how to update this docker image in the instance once it's created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the metadata.
Just to provide an example, create a Notebook instance from UI, or also from CLI:

```
gcloud compute instances create nb-container-1 \
 --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
 --image-family=common-container-notebooks \
 --machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
 --accelerator type=nvidia-tesla-t4,count=1 \
 --maintenance-policy TERMINATE \
 --metadata="proxy-mode=project_editors,install-nvidia-driver=True,container=gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu101:m49" \
 --boot-disk-size 200GB \
 --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
 --zone=asia-southeast1-b
```

or

```
gcloud beta notebooks instances create nb-container-2 \
'--machine-type=n1-standard-1' \
'--container-repository=gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu101' \
'--container-tag=m49' \
'--accelerator-type=NVIDIA_TESLA_T4' \
'--accelerator-core-count=1' \
--install-gpu-driver \
'--location=europe-west3-a'
```

Once instance is created you can do the following:

1. Stop instance
2. [Edit](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/remove-metadata) metadata to latest tag:

```
container=gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/base-cu101:latest
```

3. Start instance

Comment: TFYR. 
One question: doing this change pull the latest image **every** time that I start the notebook machine?

Comment: Correct, we will do a docker pull using the startup scripts during VM boot up process. Using the Notebooks API we can do an image update upon request (Upgrade). I don't think we support container base image updates using Notebooks API as if you set the tag to be latest, automatically we will update it during VM startup. What would be your desired scenario?

Comment: Thx. I think that works for us, we want to give to our DS team a instance fully setup that we could update regularly without disrupting their work. Now I had to figure out how to automate the update :)

Comment: Just to add more details, we support Manual Upgrade using Upgrade endpoint in API and we recently added support for Auto-Upgrade for Notebooks. (UI change will appear in the next couple of weeks). Basically you enable Auto-upgrade and define when you want the upgrade to happen via a cron job format metadata field.